# VBA Error 1004 in function

Tags: vba, types

I'm trying to write a function which returns the value of a specific cell located on the same column as the one I give in argument, (lig= row number, col=column number), but everytime I run it, I get an error '1004", here's my code:

```
Function week(lig As Integer, col As Integer) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Do Until Cells(lig - i, 1) = "Row labels"
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    week = Cells(lig - i, col)
End Function
```

The line in which the error appears is :

```
 Do Until Cells(lig - i, 1) = "Row labels"
```

I know that I test the values of cells containing integers before getting to this one, I suspeect a type error, but I can't fix it. 
Could anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i=0 will cause an error as the cells(0,1) does not exist in the sheet. You may also want an exit clause for if your logic is never found as you will get an error when you hit the end of the sheet. if you pass this lig =1 you will also get an error (as lig - i (1-1) would result in 0)so you may also want to handle that scenario

```
Function week(lig As Integer, col As Integer) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1'Changed to 1
    Do Until Cells(lig - i, 1) = "Row labels"
        i = i + 1
        if i > 1000000 then exit do 'Exit clause
    Loop
    if i < 1000000 then 
        week = Cells(lig - i, col)
    else
        week = 0'Handle 0's in calling code
    end if
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed trying to reach a non existant cell.

Comment: you may also want to handle col =0 as that will also cause an error

Answer (score 1):

The error isn't a type error. The problem is that you are trying to access a cell that doesn't exist. Your loop evidently fails to reach a cell that holds the value "Row labels" and eventually tries to access Cells(0,1) -- which triggers error 1004. As to why this is happening -- you haven't provided enough details to say.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the value in the cell is actually "Row Labels" or "ROW LABELS" or Row labels " or something else that doesn't actually match exactly. Try this:

```
Do Until Trim(Ucase(Cells(lig - i, 1))) = "ROW LABELS"
```

Or if you simply want to stop at row one use this:

```
Do Until lig - i = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like to consider re-writing as follows, which I think is clearer.

```
Function week(lig As Integer, col As Integer) As Integer

    Dim i As Integer

    ' Thsi function will return 0 if no row with the text is found
    week = 0

    For i = lig To 1 Step -1

        If Cells(i, 1) = "Row labels" Then
            week = Cells(i, col)
            Exit For
        End If

    Next i


End Function

' EVEN BETTER USE THIS (or similar)!

Function week(MyCell As Range) As Integer

    Dim i As Integer

    week = 0

    For i = MyCell.Row To 1 Step -1

        If MyCell.Parent.Cells(i, 1) = "Row labels" Then
            week = MyCell.Parent.Cells(i, MyCell.Column)
            Exit For
        End If

        ' Note
        ' MyCell.Parent. returns the sheet containing the cell
        ' Just using Cells(i, 1) (wihtout preceeding with "MyCell.Parent." will pick up
        ' cells on the currently active sheet, which may not be the sheet with the cell!
        '

    Next i


End Function
```